# PHP/Wordpress - How to display specific widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I was searching and i found this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

Based on this i have tried several things, one of them:

```
<?php the_widget( 'Phone'); ?>
```

It is a text widget, created in the sidebar. I was hoping with this code to get the content of widget i created with title `Phone` but however nothing is appearing. I can not display the content of the widget i created.

So my questions is, can you give an example how can i display the content of widget with widget title for example `Phone` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you should post the widgets code as well...

Answer (score 0):

The `<?php the_widget( $widget, $instance, $args ); ?>` function doesn't grab a widget you have defined in the WordPress admin. Instead it creates a new instance of a widget based on the class name of a registered widget.

If for example you wanted to display WordPress's default text widget and have it display "Hello World" then you would use,

`the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', array(
    'title' => 'Custom Widget Title',
    'text' => 'Hello World!',
    'filter' => true
) );`

If for example you use `register_widget('Foo_Bar_Class');` to create a custom widget then you would use the following to display a custom instance of the widget outside of a sidebar.

`the_widget('Foo_Bar_Class', array(
    'title' => 'My Foo Bar Widget',
    'custom_widget_argument' => 'Some custom value.'
);`